# Japanese localization for the common phrase "powered by x"

Tags: translation

There exists a common English phrase;

> Powered by x

Meaning something along the lines of;

> This thing is (made possible by/built upon/built with/runs on) (x)

Use case examples:

- This website is powered by WordPress
- Powered by Google

What would be a suitable Japanese localization for this phrase?

I can only think of more literal translations, such as;

- このサイトはワードプレスで作成しました
- グーグルで創造しました

And variations to this effect.

Comment: It's a very silicon-valley wording. I don't think you can easily find an apposite phrase in any other language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a single-word catchy equivalent. If you really need a translation, you can say:

> - WordPressで作成されています / ～で作成しました
> - Googleの技術により運営されています
> - AWS上で動作しています

But IMHO it's often a good idea to leave it untranslated if this is a small remark in a footer pane. "Powered by" does look somewhat cooler than the lengthy Japanese phrases above, and Japanese IT workers who may be interested in such information can understand "powered by", anyway.

(Of course there is a reason [not to say this at all](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/hide-powered-by/), but that's another story.)

As an aside, 創造 is a very big word that is used for truly innovative creations or the genesis creation.